# PHP and AlertDialog not in sync on Android

Tags: java, php, android, database, android-alertdialog

I'm currently building a simple login Android app using a tutorial on YouTube that fetches data from a database and lets the user login. However, when I click the login button, regardless of what the input is, it tells me that the login has been successful. Below is the Java code where the data is entered and the PHP code to connect to the database, every time login is clicked the AlertDialog will pop up saying 'Login successful'. I want it to display 'Login not successful' if the data the user enters is incorrect, can somebody show me how? Thanks

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "";
        if (type.equals("Login")) {
            try {
                String userName = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("userName", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(userName, "utf-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "utf-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result ="";
                String line ="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login status: ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

====

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$userName = $_POST["userName"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$mysql_qry = "select * from database where userName like '$userName' and password like '$password';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "Successful login";
}
else{
    echo "Login not successful";
}
```

Comment: To make it easier for us to help you, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means only posting the parts of your code which are necessary for us to answer your question.

Comment: Okay thanks, I removed the excess code that wasn't needed, are you able to help me?

Comment: I personally can't help you, as I don't know PHP well, but posting good examples will help the people who *can* help you in doing so.

Comment: Òkay thanks I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

In your conn.php file

```
$dbname = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$server = "";
```

This should not be empty.

Fill it with appropriate data

Comment: Hi, in my file it isn't empty, it just is here in the interest of privacy

Comment: If you are new to this may I suggest a wonderful alternative to all this boiler plate code? Use google volly. or use the library shown in this tutorial : https://youtu.be/BUwMVIaN3Fc?list=PL0DVoqvV_TdjXF61yGKYGTycSOYEwTSeJ

Comment: Thanks but I'm going to go ahead with the stuff I have for now. Just need to get my current code working